# how to avoid manual work of copying dll files to other PC

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-assembly, gac

how acually DLL concept works for vb.net project

I have included Microsoft.office.interop.excel dll and sqlite dll

but in other PC, excel dll gets automatically installed with setup
while sqlite dll, I need to manually put in GAC

why it is so ??

any solution, so that I can avoid manual work of copying...

Answer (score 0):

You could provide an installer/setup with your application to install the assemblies in the GAC. Or just provide all the assemblies in the same directory as your application. If the assemblies are not yours, then please check if and how you can redistribute it.